# AWS service to track entity in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a simple app in AWS which lets user rent out cars for limited amount of time. I am using AWS Lambda for computation, dynamoDB for storage and API Gateway to handle requests to lambda functions.
My question is if there is any AWS service or dynamoDB feature that allows me to track time for "Car" object in dynamoDB such that when rental time is over, it triggers a lambda function to notify the user and perform other action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB Streams and TTL are not good solutions because DynamoDB provides no SLA for TTL deletes (it can even take longer than 48 hours in rare cases) and the item will be deleted so cannot be used by downstream applications or analytics later on.

For this you should use Cloudwatch event rules (or Amazon Eventbridge) with a cron schedule expression. So your code that puts the item into the DynamoDB table can subsequently create a Cloudwatch event rule for the time in the future when the rental time will expire, using a cron schedule expression. This will trigger a lambda that can call your notification service to notify the customer.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using [DynamoDB Time to Live](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) along with [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html) and a lambda function.

In this scenario, the items specific to the rental time would be placed in a **separate table**. They would have TTL values set to the rental time. DynamoDB **automatically scans** and deletes items based on the TTL. These automatic deletions could be picked up by DynamoDB streams and forwarded to a **lambda function**. The function would take action based on the expired time.

However, a [possible issue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) could be that sometimes DynamoDB will take 48 hours to delete an item.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, that wouldn’t be a problem as long as lambda function is called as soon as TTL is over? Or does that also take time?

Comment: @JakeHemmington Lambda is invoked on deletion of expired item, not on TTL expiration. I don't know how often such large delays happen, but they are a possibility.

Comment: Cool solution.  Why would you store the rental specific items in a separate table?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan DynamoDB delete items when TTL expires. It could be safer to keep them in separate table to avoid deleting main items with all client information. Also if the second table is smaller and lighter then the primary one, the risk of large TTL deletion delay could be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be having a Lambda cron job that runs on a timer that scans or queries the DynamoDB table for values that have a date matching the end date of the rental. This lambda could then invoke your NotifyUser lambda using AWS Step Functions, or could emit an event to a SNS Topic where your lambda has subscribed to.

Some links that may be helpful:
[CronJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)
[SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-package.html)